# Switch between content on TKinter / Python

Tags: python, tkinter

i am fairly new to using TKinter together with Python, and i am actually wondering if there is an option to switch the content i am seeing by pressing a simple button.

So here a basic code:

```
    from tkinter import *

def doNothing():
    print("ok ok I won't ...")

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x300+200+100")


# *** Creating Dropdown on Top ***

menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)

subMenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=subMenu)
subMenu.add_command(label="New Project...", command=doNothing)
subMenu.add_command(label="Settings", command=doNothing)
subMenu.add_separator()
subMenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=doNothing)

editMenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=editMenu)
editMenu.add_command(label="Redo", command=doNothing)

# *** Creating Toolbar ***

toolbar = Frame(root, bg="blue", )

uebersichtButton = Button(toolbar, text="Übersicht", command=doNothing)
uebersichtButton.pack(side=LEFT, padx=2, pady=2)
kundenButton = Button(toolbar, text="Kunden", command=doNothing)
kundenButton.pack(side=LEFT, padx=2, pady=2)
hilfeButton = Button(toolbar, text="Hilfe", command=doNothing)
hilfeButton.pack(side=LEFT, padx=2, pady=2)

toolbar.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)

root.mainloop()
```

In generell i want to switch to different Layouts in the part below the Toolbar part.

Is this still part of TKinter or done in Python itself?

appreciate any help and hope ive made my question understandable.

Kind regards
Confused

Comment: Any sample GUI to show what you want to achieve?

Comment: ive already gone through programs when opening the question, but none had come to my mind till now. It shall always show the Toolbar and Menu on top, and if i switch the named buttons, the part below shall change. Just like : uebersicht shows details about certain things; Kunden shows a part of a database with data of them and hilfe, well shows help ^^